# Verifying that an inequality has a finite limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to verify the following inequality using Mathematica, but without any success.

$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{\intop_{0}^{1}e^{\frac{-30}{\sqrt[15]{a^{16}*\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}}}*xdx}{e^{\frac{-32}{a}}}<+\infty.
$$

Mathematica just retrieves the same expression after a couple of minutes.

Comment: Have you tried numerics? The limit appears to be zero.

Comment: It is really strange to see $*$ to denote multiplication. `*` is used for this only in computer languages, not in textbook notation. $*$ normally means convolution or other uncommon or specialized operations.

Comment: Please provide the actual code you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do the integral first and then take the limit, you get an answer, but not the one you want.

```
int = Integrate[x/E^(30/(a^16*Log[1/x])^(1/15)), {x, 0, 1}]
(* (Sqrt[15]*MeijerG[{{}, {}}, {{0, 1/15, 2/15, 1/5, 4/15, 1/3, 2/5, 
      7/15, 8/15, 3/5, 2/3, 11/15, 4/5, 13/15, 14/15, 1}, {}}, 
    65536/a^16])/(256*Pi^7) *)
```

In your preferred direction:

```
limabove=Limit[int/E^(-32/a), a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(* Long Rational Answer *)
```

Get a numerical answer.

```
N[limabove, 50]//Chop
(* ∞ *)
```

The `Chop` gets rid of the small imaginary part due to numerical round off error.

If you evaluate in the other direction you get zero

```
Limit[int/E^(-32/a), a -> 0, Direction -> "FromBelow"]
(* 0 *)
```

but that does take awhile.

Comment: I could not run the code: limabove=Limit[int/E^(-32/a), a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]. Mathematica says that:   Limit::ldir: Value of Direction -> FromAbove should be a number or Automatic. >>

Then I tried: limabove=Limit[int/E^(-32/a), a -> 0, Direction -> -1"], but it retrieves the same expression without calculating.

Comment: The code works for Version 12.  The options `"FromAbove"` and `"FromBelow"` are fairly new and may not be available if you are using an older Mathematica version.  The directions `+1` and `-1` have been around awhile and should work in older versions, but an older version may not have as good limit finding capabilities as newer versions.  You have not said what version you are using.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9. I should update it now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bill, does Mathematica use background network to improve its computation? I did install Mathematica 12 and run the code you gave (internet off), but it took so long to evaluate the limit, now I still don't get the answer.

Comment: Internet is not required to run and I don't think it speeds things up, but it did take me quite awhile to run and I have a pretty fast gaming computer.

Comment: I just reran them with Timing.  The times in seconds for the four commands were 15, 335, 0, 273.  I got the same results, but it does take awhile.

Comment: Thanks. Hix, my MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), 1.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 4G Ram seems to be outdated. It could not give the limit after 2 hours. Would you mind to share the configuration of your gaming computer?

Comment: It's also sad to see the conjecture to be false, according to your mathematica.

Comment: I do not guarantee the answer is correct, because Mma not always is.  I do not know how to tell for sure.  My computer is Windows 10 with a 4 Ghz Intel i7 processor, Nvidia 1080 gtx graphics.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.